# Should Single Quotes Be Used for Multiple Row MySQL UPDATEs?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, query, standards

When you are performing a SQL UPDATE on multiple rows in MySQL, it seems that you can either put single quotes around every value or not and it will produce the same results.

Is there a reason for using single quotes in an UPDATE query if not using single quotes produces the same results? Is there any difference at all?

**Example without quotes:**

```
UPDATE superuser
SET poop = rainbows
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

**Example with quotes:**

```
UPDATE superuser
SET poop = rainbows
WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3');
```

Comment: Are you asking what the difference between the two queries are?

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes, I am asking if there is any difference. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you have ran each query, and return what the results would have been, before asking this question?  *Just switch the UPDATE to SELECT and get rid of the SET.*

Answer (score 0):

In general, quote all strings and unquote numbers. Your SQL will, however, break if there are single quotes on the string, so escape the single quote by doubling it.

```
SELECT * FROM superuser WHERE poop = 'johnny''s'
-- note how the string [johnny's] have double quotes
```

On the other hand, quoting numbers in SQL is bad. Although SQL implicitly tries to convert these values, it could lead to unwanted results. Say, you have a CHAR type and you feed it an unquoted `1` instead of a quoted `'1'`, you'd get the character in the 1st position of the charset instead of an actual '1' character.